# How to resolve "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" after a DB reset

Tags: sql-server

**Use Case:**
I am performing performance execution on an database and I am trying to do following:
I took an backup of the database (the mdf and ldf file) at the early stage (lets called a "**baselinecopy**").
After that I execute some performance script .And the database reach to **baselinecopy+Additional_Row** (let it be "NewDatabase") from the test.

Then I replace the database **baselinecopy with NewDatabase** & start the server. While trying to perform operation on application it is giving me Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint to test_order. Cannot insert duplicate key in object.

I check the "IDENTITY" but the table has no identity set.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: How does the table object look like?

Comment: Your question does not have anywhere near enough information for anybody to give you any real help. We can't see your screen and have no idea what you are trying to do. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint to test_order. Cannot insert duplicate key in object.

This is exactly what it says.

You have defined a primary key on a table and are attempting to insert a record that contains the same primary key as an existing record.

It does not need to be an identity column to be a primary key column.

Comment: Why it is sending the same key again ? any thoughts on it because after a DB service restart everything should be in sync.

Comment: This is all your data. Nobody can tell you why something is "sending the same key again". You would need to examine the data you're attempting to insert and compare it with the primary key constraint on your table.

Comment: If you post your table structure along with the primary key column list and your data, we can take a look.